# El segundo indice del metódo indexOf y lastIndexOf no funciona correctamente

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-metodo

Mi preocupacion es el porque a yo ejecutar un segundo indice en "`indexOf`" o "`lasIndexOf`", éstos no empiezan desde ahí y no acaban tampoco donde se especifica.

```js
let a = "Buenos dias, que dia, diabolico"
console.log(a.indexOf("dia", 15))
```

**Consola: 17**

Comment: Si esta funcionando bien, creo que estas confundido en como funciona, lo que hace es empezar a buscar desde el índice que le indicas y al encontrar una coincidencia te devolverá el índice en el cual encontró la coincidencia pero será el índice como si contara desde el principio no desde donde le indicaste que empezara a buscar

Comment: ¿Qué esperabas? La primera coincidencia, empezando la búsqueda en la posición 15, empieza en la posición 17

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, le estas pasando un segundo parametro entero que es menor a ``a.length``, por lo tanto el metodo empezara a buscar desde ahi. Entonces devuelve 17 que es la posicion donde encuentra la palabra "dia". Si vos haces ``console.log(a.indexOf("dia", 3))`` empezarias a buscar desde la letra ``n`` y el resultado seria 7. Que esperabas vos? En cuantoa a ``lastIndexOf`` solo le pasas el array y te devuelve 22, que es donde comienza la palabra ``diabolico`` - Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#parameters

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes, cuando le damos un parámetro al `indexOf()`, es porque estamos buscando la posición en donde se encuentra ese parámetro en la cadena (el primero que encuentre), ejemplo:

```js
let cadena = "Buenos dias, que dia, diabolico";
console.log(cadena.indexOf("dia")); // imprime 7, ya que "dia" se encuentra en la posición 7 en la cadena.
```

Y al pasarle otro parámetro, nos referimos a que el `indexOf()` comenzará a buscar a partir de ese índice en adelante, ignorando los índices anteriores:

```js
let cadena = "Buenos dias, que dia, diabolico";
console.log(cadena.indexOf("dia", 12)); // busco a partir del índice 12 e imprime 17, ya que "dia" se encuentra en la posición 17 en la cadena cuando buscamos a partir del índice 12.
```